# If $f(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})=ax^{2}+by^{2}+cz^{2}$, what is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So this is a question of partial derivatives. If $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$, and $f(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})=ax^{2}+by^{2}+cz^{2}$ where $a$,$b$ and $c$ are constant numbers, what is $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$? Should I differentiate from both sides? I tried that and I am not really sure how to proceed from there. I kind of have a feeling that it is not the proper way to solve it. I can not think of anything. Any helps are mostly appreciated.

Comment: This is an application of the Implicit Function Theorem

Comment: Thanks for responding. How should I define $F(x,y,z)=0$, when there are squared factors inside the function?

Comment: just move everything to one side, now you have an expression equaling $0$

Comment: So if $F(x,y,z)=f(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})-ax^{2}-by^{2}-cz^{2}$, could you extend your kindness and comment whether the following is correct?$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}=-\frac{2xf_{x}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})-2ax}{2zf_{z}(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})-2by}$?

Comment: $f$ is a single variable function. It only has $f'$, $f_x$ and $f_z$ do not make sense. Also, why is there a $y$ in the denominator?

Comment: Sorry, How can $f$ be a single variable function? Is it not the case that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ which implicitly implicates that $z=f(x,y)$?

Comment: You're confusing letters. $f$ in the problem is a single variable function. $x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a single input, not a list of inputs.